# 'Uncheck call' warning after creating list view

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

For some reason, after creating my list view `new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.list_item, listContent)` becomes highlighted in yellow and a warning appears. Does anyone know what needs to be done in order to resolve this warning?

> Unchecked call to 'ArrayAdapter(Context, int, int, T[])' as a member of raw type 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter'

```
public class FragmentMainList extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public FragmentMainList() {
    }

    ListView list_main;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);

        String[] listContent = {
                getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.item_1),
                getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.item_2),
                getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.item_3)
        };

        list_main = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_main);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.list_item, listContent);
        list_main.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ArrayAdapter` is of raw type because it is templated but you haven't specified the type.

To resolve the issue:

`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.list_item, listContent);`